# ld: library not found for -lopencore-amrnb

Tags: ios, xcode

I compiled my iOS App on my own mac and it worked well.while yesterday I committed the source code to SVN and my work fellow updated all of it to compile and archive it,the error occurred as below:

```
    $ ld: library not found for -lopencore-amrnb
    $ error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

and then I tried to archive it on my own mac,it just worked fine.
We both updated our Mac system and Xcode to the newest.

I just have no idea why this happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it:I deleted the libopencore_amrnb.a in my project and committed it,then I added it into my project again and commited the project that the SVN would refresh it.Then my work fellow updated the project again from SVN,and archived with no error.
I guess it was the SVN which occurred some unexpected error that the .a file didn't committed correctly.